# PYSERIAL port array

Tags: python, pyserial

I am very new to python but little experienced with C Programming. I am trying to open and use multiple serial ports using pyserial library, and want to use array of serial ports to keep track of them for read and write operations, Below is my code:

```
try:
    ser[0] = serial.Serial(
        SERIAL_COM[0], 
        baudrate = SERIAL_BAUD_RATE, 
        timeout = SERIAL_TIMEOUT
    )
except: 
    print ("Exception occurred")
```

Above code always go into exception, However if i don't use as array i.e. changed ser[0] to ser I don't face exception. I just want to know how can i use serial port array to avoid exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not catch all exceptions per se. Instead catch specific ones... But for starters remove the try/except and try again. This will give you/us the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, i was messing up with arrays previously. Following code is working fine now:

```
ser = []
ser.append(serial.Serial(
    'COM1', 
    baudrate = SERIAL_BAUD_RATE, 
    timeout = SERIAL_TIMEOUT
))
```

If i need to add another port, i will just call ser.append() and port can be accessed through identifier ser[i].